How to POST a file to Paperless NGX API with CSRF token and Basic Authentication in PHP?
I am trying to upload a file from my local server to the Paperless NGX API using PHP. The API requires a CSRF token and Basic Authentication for the POST request. However, I am having trouble obtaining the CSRF token and making the request successfully. Here is the code I have written so far:

Getting the CSRF Token:


$apiUrl = 'http://hostname:8000/api/documents/post_document/';
$filePath = '/path/to/file.pdf';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

function getCsrfToken($apiUrl, $username, $password) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = [];
    $header_text = substr($response, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
    foreach (explode("\r\n", $header_text) as $i => $line) {
        if ($i === 0) {
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        } else {
            list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);
            $headers[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $headers['X-CSRFToken'] ?? null;
}

$csrfToken = getCsrfToken($apiUrl, $username, $password);

if (!$csrfToken) {
    die('CSRF-Token could not be retrieved');
}


Uploading the file:

    $ch = curl_init();

    $file = new CURLFile($filePath);

    $postData = [
        'document' => $file
    ];

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'X-CSRFToken: ' . $csrfToken,
        'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
    ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($httpCode == 201) {
        echo 'File uploaded successfully!';
    } else {
        echo 'Error uploading file: ' . $response;
    }
}

uploadFile($apiUrl, $filePath, $csrfToken, $username, $password);

However, when I run this code, I receive a "405 Method Not Allowed" response when attempting to get the CSRF token. I suspect that the API URL I am using to get the CSRF token is incorrect, or the method I am using to retrieve it is not supported.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly retrieve the CSRF token and successfully upload a file to the Paperless NGX API with Basic Authentication in PHP?
Thank you!

You're posting to the wrong API endpoint there to get your token, and you're not passing the credentials correctly. https://docs.paperless-ngx.com/api/#authorization: "POST a username and password as a form or json string to /api/token/ and paperless will respond with a token, if the login data is correct. "

I'm using basic authentication as described in the documentation.

If you are indeed talking about the API token - "POST a username and password as a form or json string to /api/token/"
